# Separate javascript in to own .js file

Tags: javascript, html, file, src

You may see a JS below which is now commented which is now copied in `all-set.js` without two `<script>` lines.

It was working when I was using the code in head, now it's not.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="all-set.js" ></script>

    <!--
    <SCRIPT language="javascript" >
    $(function(){

        // add multiple select / deselect functionality
        $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });

        // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
        // and viceversa
        $(".case").click(function(){

            if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
            }

        });
    });
    </SCRIPT> 
    -->
</head>
```

Comment: you should put `<script type="text/javascript" src="all-set.js" ></script> ` at the very end of your html. just before `</body>`

Comment: Are you sure that the path to the `all-set.js` is correct?

Comment: @epipav I tried also that

Comment: @TasosK. yes the name is correct

Comment: @Luxqs then you should definitely inform us more about your problem. what is the console output you are getting?

Comment: What is your directory structure? Where is the JS and where is the HTML file? Are they right besides each other in the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your directory structure?

Where is the `JS` and where is the `HTML` file?

Are they right besides each other in the same folder?

If yes, try changing `src` of your `script` tag like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./all-set.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the JS file remove the script tags. These don't have to be there:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" >
</SCRIPT>
```

Also, as a general rule, always use lower-case tags in HTML.

Comment: he already stated that he has removed them. _You may see a JS below which is now commented which is now copied in all-set.js without two <script> lines._